# ETL: doing a join across different sources with different field type

Tags: sql, join, types, etl, informatica

For an application that does ETL across multiple sources, how are joins handled where the "value" may be the same, but how it is represented could be different. For example, let's take the following made-up scenario:

**Source1**

- ProductID: `909` // an int
- Product: `"Soda"`

**Source2**

- ProductID: `"909"` // a string
- ActionType: `"Click"`

---

Let's say these are from two different source that I don't have access to modify (for example, one might be Salesforce data and the other is a company database). How might an ETL application handle joins where the field types may be stored differently?

Comment: Hi - this would be entirely dependent on the ETL application being used. There is no generic answer. Do you have a specific ETL tool in mind and, if so, please could you update your question and also tag it appropriately? Thanks

Comment: @NickW this is more a general question, I don't have any particular ETL tool in mind, but more conceptually what might be the options (always cast to string might be the most general, though dates throw a wrench in that). Do you know of how any specific ETL tools handle this?

Comment: Generally, data should be held in fields of the appropriate type so I would always convert to the relevant type e.g. timestamp as a timestamp rather than as a string. Also bear in mind that how data is displayed is not necessarily how it is stored, particularly with date/timestamp data

Comment: @NickW right, let's assume I don't have control/ownership over how the data is stored. So it's more a WYSIWYG in terms of how I may have to possibly join the data.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your questions is, other than to have a philosophical discussion. Given that Stackoverflow is here to answer specific technical questions and is not a discussion forum, I think I'll probably stop at this point

Comment: i think this is a core capability of ETL. Extract and Transform data into the shape you need. First extract the data from your different sources into a staging area, then transform the data, in this case change the data type of one of the source key fields, then move on from there. This is one of the most common reasons to have a staging area in the first place, you need a place to store intermediate/temp data before it is ready to be joined and loaded into the destination system.

Comment: I too think I'm missing the point. In one layer of the ETL process you load the data knowing the sources' correct data types. The next layer transforms the data types to whatever you need, provided the data conforms to expectations (the string being numeric only, for example).  All that can be in a database, or part of external processing.  ETL is just a pipeline of processing, there's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this problem in many legacy databases. The fact that tables reside in different sources is not relevant, since I've seen this happenning in the same schema, in separate schemas, and also separate databases.

There are two aspects to the question: feasability and performance.

**Feasibility**

All databases I know support data type conversion and casting. Some of them do it silently behind the scenes, and they tend to do it wrong. For example, Oracle is notorious in this aspect, since it tends to convert in the wrong direction. I recommend to **always do it explicitly**.

For example (PostgreSQL):

```
create table a (product_id int, name varchar(10));
                                             
insert into a (product_id, name) values (909, 'soda');
                                             
create table b (product_id varchar(10), action_type varchar(10));
                                             
insert into b (product_id, action_type) values ('909', 'click');
```

In PostgreSQL the following three queries work, and they produce the same result set (performance is a different story):

```
select * from a join b on a.product_id = b.product_id; -- don't do this

select * from a join b on a.product_id = cast(b.product_id as int);

select * from a join b on cast(a.product_id as varchar) = b.product_id;
```

If you type the first option, the engine will silently convert it into the second or third query without you knowing. This can produce unexpected/unnecessary errors you may fail to appropriately address. Again, always do explicit conversion.

**Performance**

When performance comes to play, it's important to decide which table will be the *driving table*, and which one will be the *secondary table*.

If you decide `a` will be the driving table, then you'll probably do two things:

- Convert on the `b` side, as in:

  ```
   select * from a join b on a.product_id = cast(b.product_id as int);
  ```
- Optionally speed the query further by (if you can) creating an expression index (or an indexed virtual index) on `cast(b.product_id as int)` as in:

  ```
   create index ix1 on b ((cast(b.product_id as int)));
  ```

On the other side, if you decide `b` will be the driving table, then you'll probably do:

- Convert on the `a` side, as in:

  ```
   select * from a join b on cast(a.product_id as varchar) = b.product_id;
  ```
- Optionally, speed the query further by (if you can) creating an expression index (or an indexed virtual index) on `cast(a.product_id as varchar)` as in:

  ```
   create index ix2 on a ((cast(a.product_id as varchar))));
  ```

To decide which option is better, you'll need to get the execution plan of both, read the estimated costs, and decide. Sometimes the estimated costs are not that reliable: they are *estimated* only, not the real thing. In critical cases I would end up running both options to compare.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the data from each source
2. Cast to same datatype
3. Join

All within the ETL tool of your choice. Where's the catch, as I'm apparently missing it?...

Here's how you can achieve it in [Informatica](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788471220/4/ch04lvl1sec40/joiner-transformation).

Answer (score 1):

I will apply the following approach:

- create a functionality to identify the columns types
- map the columns type to text representation
- cast to the maximum text length needed to hold the values
- join the data

I have the same scenario in the context of one database and apply this approach. It's because a functionality to query dynamic set of columns from the database and perform various SQL operations over them.

One of the operator is [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example). The T-SQL statement build is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
     SELCET RowID
           ,Col001
           ,Col002
           ...
           ,Col00X
     FROM ...
) DS
UNPIVOT
(
  [value] FOR [column] IN ([Col001], [Col002], ... , [Col00X])
) UNPVT;
```

The issue is all columns in the `UNPIVOT` `IN` clause must have the same type. Of course the most easier fix is to `CAST/CONVERT` all columns to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as it pretty much can store everything and we did, but the execution time of the queries was huge.

So, it was better if the largest type can be hold in `VARCHAR(X)` or `NVARCHNAR(X)` to cast the columns to it. I write a simple [SQL CLR Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-ver15) function as I have all the columns names and types in table and wanted to get the destination type fast and clear. It looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
[
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate
    (
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.Format.UserDefined,
        IsInvariantToNulls = true,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
        IsInvariantToOrder = false,
        MaxByteSize = -1
    )
]
/// <summary>
/// Returns the data type with highest precedence. The date types comes in the "[system_type_name]" format.
/// </summary>
public class AnalysisCustomRollupsGetHighestDataTypeConverstionValue : Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize
{
    private Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> dataTypesMapping;
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> destinationDataTypes;
    private String[] dataTypesWithoutPredifinedLength;

    public void Init()
    {
        // for the following data types the length is extracting from the input value
        dataTypesWithoutPredifinedLength = new string[] {"nvarchar", "nchar", "varchar", "char"};

        // each data type is mapped to its string corresponding value ("-1" is "MAX", "0" is defined by source)
        dataTypesMapping = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> {
                                                                                {"user-defined data types", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"sql_variant", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"xml", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"datetimeoffset", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 34)},
                                                                                {"datetime2", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 27)},
                                                                                {"datetime", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 19)},
                                                                                {"smalldatetime", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 19)},
                                                                                {"date", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 19)},
                                                                                {"time", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 16)},
                                                                                {"float", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 48)},
                                                                                {"real", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 48)},
                                                                                {"decimal", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 48)},
                                                                                {"money", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 19)},
                                                                                {"smallmoney", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 10)},
                                                                                {"bigint", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 26)},
                                                                                {"int", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 14)},
                                                                                {"smallint", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 7)},
                                                                                {"tinyint", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 3)},
                                                                                {"bit", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 1)},
                                                                                {"ntext", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"text", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"image", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"timestamp", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 8)},
                                                                                {"uniqueidentifier", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 36)},
                                                                                {"nvarchar", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", 0)},
                                                                                {"nchar", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", 0)},
                                                                                {"varchar", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 0)},
                                                                                {"char", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("VARCHAR", 0)},
                                                                                {"varbinary", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)},
                                                                                {"binary", new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("NVARCHAR", -1)}
                                                                            };

        destinationDataTypes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString value)
    {
        string[] buffer;
        string currentDataTypeName;
        int currentDataLength;
        
        if (value.IsNull)
        {
            return;
        }

        buffer = value.Value.Split('(', ')');
     
        currentDataTypeName = buffer[0].ToLower();
        
        // length is extracting from the source value
        if (dataTypesWithoutPredifinedLength.Contains(currentDataTypeName))
        {
            if(buffer[1].ToUpper() == "MAX")
            {
                buffer[1] = "-1";
            }

            Int32.TryParse(buffer[1], out currentDataLength);

            destinationDataTypes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(currentDataTypeName, currentDataLength));
        }
        // length is predefined
        else
        {
            destinationDataTypes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(dataTypesMapping[currentDataTypeName].Key, dataTypesMapping[currentDataTypeName].Value));
        }
    }

    public void Merge(AnalysisCustomRollupsGetHighestDataTypeConverstionValue other)
    {
        destinationDataTypes = destinationDataTypes.Union(other.destinationDataTypes).ToList();
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        string output;
        string length;
  
        length = (destinationDataTypes.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First().Value == -1 ? "MAX" : destinationDataTypes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Value.ToString());
        
        output = (destinationDataTypes.Exists(x => String.Equals(x.Key.ToUpper(), "NVARCHAR")) ? "NVARCHAR" : "VARCHAR") + "(" + length + ")";
      
        return new SqlString(output);
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        if (r == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("r");

        int count = r.ReadInt32();
        destinationDataTypes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            destinationDataTypes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int> (r.ReadString(), r.ReadInt32()));
        }
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        if (w == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("w");

        w.Write(destinationDataTypes.Count);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> record in destinationDataTypes)
        {
            w.Write(record.Key);
            w.Write(record.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

and it allows me to do this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsGetHighestDataTypeConverstionValue] ([column_type])
FROM 
(
    VALUES ('VARCHAR(5)')
          ,('INT')
          ,('SMALLMONEY')
) DS ([column_type]);
```

which returns `VARCHAR(14)`.

I guess in your ETL process this will be simpler to achieve.

What will be more difficult is to handle the dates. In my context all dates comes in this format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS` as strings. If you need to join dates and some of them comes as string in different formats like `2010 5th May` or `something crazy enter in input without any validation` you will need to convert them first to dates and then to strings.